# How to prevent Hyper-V VM from turning-off numlock (Win 11 gen 2)

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v, numlock

I have a numerical keypad which i use for entering numbers. Normally, when my windows starts(Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22621) the numlock is enabled.
However whenever I start a Hyper-V VM (gen 2) it turns of the numlock and this is really annoying.
Is there a way to prevent that starting of VM turns of my numlock?

Comment: This would be handled by the virtualized UEFI firmware which Microsoft has disabled us from entering on VM boot.  I believe that the states controlled by the virtualized firmware can be accessed through WMI's "MsVM_virtualSystemManagementService" class.   Someone [wrapped parts of it with powershell](https://github.com/gcbond/pshyperv/blob/master/HyperV/VMConfig.ps1) but I am not sure if the key lock stuff is in there or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and tried different solutions to fix it, but no one out of googled approaches really helpedregistry key:

Finally, I found only one working solution to fix the NumLock issue. It's to create a PowerShell script at VM, let's call it for example 'NumlockEnable.ps1' with the following content:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
if ([console]::NumberLock -eq $false) {
   $WshShell.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")
}
```

And make the script run at logon, for example by using Group Policy Object (GPO), according to the [instructions](https://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/).

Also, in my case (Windows 10 Guest OS), the following registry key has to be set to the next value

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="80000002"
```

P.S. Of course, this is a crutch, but everything else does not work